# how to track a uop's flag in microprocessor?

Tags: computer-architecture

Lots of processor renaming their register to achieve the goal of out-of-order,but how to track the instruction's flag,such as carry flag,overflow flag,etc?

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you are anticipating?  Register renaming doesn't cause any difficulties for the flags that I'm aware of.  Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking and what you think the issue is.

Comment: If this is about how real-world processors do things, it's offtopic here.